# Laravel cache with events and webhooks

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-cache

I'm trying to implement the "processing" button functionality to use with a set of api calls called through a series of events and corresponding listeners.

I'm using Pusher with Echo, which seem to work fine, but to ensure the status is showing on page reload I also utilise Laravel's cache, which on the initial call sets the key with the value (`Cache::put('key', 1)`) and after the final call it should remove the entry using `Cache::forget('key')`.

Both cache method are called from within the event subscriber class:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Server\Listeners;

use App\Server\Events\InitialSyncServerRequested;
use App\Server\Events\SyncServerFinished;
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

class SyncCacheSubscriber
{
    public function setCache(InitialSyncServerRequested $event): void
    {
        Cache::put('syncServer', $event->serverId);
    }

    public function clearCache(): void
    {
        Cache::forget('syncServer');
    }

    public function subscribe(Dispatcher $events): array
    {
        return [
            InitialSyncServerRequested::class => 'setCache',
            SyncServerFinished::class => 'clearCache',
        ];
    }
}
```

I've tried using different cache drivers to no avail.

I'm using Redis for both queuing and caching.

Events are being called in succession - once the previous listener finished processing it calls the next event so there is no asynchronous issue.

I've verified that all events are being dispatched and all in the correct order, however the clearing of cache does not take place.

Comment: You may encounter sync issues with this approach because the event is processed asynchronously after it is constructed at a time you can't know beforehand. You should consider to implement an event handler that listens for these events and manipulates the cache instead

Comment: I tried moving the cache calls to the handle method of the corresponding listeners, but that also did not play well.

Comment: Also - the events are triggered manually from the the previous listener - they aren't chained so asynchronous does not apply here as the next job would not exist on the queue unless the previous one has completed.

Comment: You really need to share the listener code instead of the event code. The event objects are not meant to have side-effects they are meant to only be data objects that the listeners can use.

Comment: I've changed approach to the event subscriber, but the issue persist.

Answer (score 0):

Ok mystery resolved!

The system I'm working with uses multi-tenancy and the issue was that when the first event was triggered, the cache prefix was generated using the application domain variable `ADMIN_HOST` i.e. `mydomain_cache_:`, wheres when queued it was using key generated using `APP_NAME` variable i.e. `myapplication_cache_:`. Hence, because of the cache prefix it set the cookie with the first event, but did not clear it with the second because it was looking at the wrong cache container.